# UIActionSheet Cancel button is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, uiactionsheet

`UIActionSheet` , it has buttons with title ,I am fetching the title from the array .I want to get the buttons title and displaying in `UILabel`, that i did , but if I  press cancel button the cancel buttons also displaying ,I dont want to display the cancel button title in `UILabel`
 the below code which i have tried ,

```
 - (IBAction)site_Selection:(id)sender {

NSArray *array = @[@"one",@"two",@"three",@"Smart Gladiator1"];

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:nil
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:nil
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
actionSheet.delegate = self;
for (NSString *title in array) {
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
}

actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];


[actionSheet showInView:self.view];


   }

     -(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

NSString *title = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];


self.btn_site_selection.titleLabel.text =  [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

 }
```

Please help me to do this ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not handle the cancel button press.

Since all button presses on `UIActionSheet` are handled by `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` you will need to check if the button index is that of the cancel button. You can do this with the `cancelButtonIndex` on `UIActionSheet`:

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if  (actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex == buttonIndex) {
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
- (IBAction)actionSheetCall:(id)sender {


    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Confirm call"
                                                                   message:@"Are you sure to call?"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet]; // 1

    UIAlertAction *secondAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                              NSLog(@"You pressed cancel button ");
                                                          }]; // 3


    for(int i = 0; i < [Arr_phone count]; i++) {

        UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[activity.Arr_phone objectAtIndex:i]
                                                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                                  NSLog(@"You pressed Logout one");
                                                                  //[self setupCall];
                                                                  [self incomingCall:[Arr_phone objectAtIndex:i]];
                                                              }]; // 2
        [alert addAction:firstAction]; // 4

    }

    [alert addAction:secondAction]; // 5

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]; // 6


}
```